# Broadcom 4322 Rev 01 - unable to find suitable driver

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Hi I visited [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395) and could not find my broadcom wireless network listed here.  I'm pretty sure I scanned over everything.

What driver do I use for bcm4322 rev 01 this is my output of

```
lschw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4322 802.11bgn Wireless Network Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d3200000-d3203fff
```

and the output of

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4322 802.11bgn Wireless Network Controller [14e4:4322] (rev 01)
```

Note: I have tried bcmwl-kernel-source and firmware-b43-installer.

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot?

Comment: It’s an iMac - no secure boot

Comment: Do `sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install --reinstall firmware-b43-installer` then reboot

Comment: I fully purged them and installed the other driver.

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason, perhaps just an update, an Additional Driver became listed "broadcom" and I installed it.  And it works fine, now.